# how to align customViews on a NavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uinavigationbar

I am having problems trying to align 2 customViews on the `NavigationItem.titleView`. I have read the documentations and found out that the titleView is aligned in the center. Is there any way to align my view on the left or right of the NavigationController? Below shows you 2 images:

[image: Search bar covering a text field]
search bar is covering a text field

[image: Ideal output, taken online so smudge all other stuff]
ideal output

**EDIT:**
I have attempted another to deal with this, use a ToolBar instead of a NavigationController. ToolBar idea works, but how do I set a title like the NavigationBar which have a .prompt property? Adding a label will have very little space left for me to do anything. Please advice, I have been working on this for the whole day and I cannot solve this minor problem :(

[image: toolbar]
failed toolbar

Answer (score 0):

use a tool bar instead. if its a navigation controller, hide the navigation bar and add the tool bar... i think thats the easiest way...

Comment: wouldnt it be better if i remove the nav controller and just add a toolbar then? but can toolbar have a title? i havent checked the documentation for it yet...

Comment: you can add custom views to toolbar

Comment: i do not see in the documentation that it can add custom views, what is the name of the method?

Comment: i mean you can create tool bar buttons with custom view (for title, use a UILabel) and add them to the tool bar...

Comment: ah, i see... im experimenting it right now, but how do i make the toolbar wider?

Comment: hmm... thats not possible.. i guess you're just gonna have to use a UIView with a background image view with the bar like image, add your title view etc on it where ever you want... it'll look just like the nav/tool bar..